# PHP MySql Pagination?

Tags: php, mysql

Pagination really confuses me. My code works but it only shows the first page. The next page doesn't work. I just want to show 3 records per page.
Do you have to have another query to show the results of the second page?

```
<?php 

 // Connects to your Database 

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("db_pet") or die(mysql_error()); 


 //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 

 if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 



 //Here we count the number of results 

 //Edit $data to be your query 

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_pet") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 



 //This is the number of results displayed per page 

 $page_rows = 3; 



 //This tells us the page number of our last page 

 $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 



 //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 

 if ($pagenum < 1) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 

 elseif ($pagenum > $last) 

 { 

 $pagenum = $last; 

 } 



 //This sets the range to display in our query 

$max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 






 //This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it

 $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_pet $max") or die(mysql_error()); 


 //This is where you display your query results

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data_p)) 

 { 

 Print $info['pet_name']; 

 echo "<br>";

 } 

 echo "<p>";


 // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages

echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";


 // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

 if ($pagenum == 1) 

 {

 } 

 else 

 {

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";

 echo " ";

 $previous = $pagenum-1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";

 } 


 //just a spacer

echo " ---- ";


 //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

 if ($pagenum == $last) 

 {

 } 

 else {

 $next = $pagenum+1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

 echo " ";

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";

 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: I don't see how you pass page number to your code. Should be like `$pagenum = isset($_GET['pagenum']) ? (int)$_GET['pagenum'] : 1`

Comment: See comment above, second your result never returns any different results without a LIMIT from the offset from and to the page rows (10 results per page, 0,9 - 10,19, etc).

Comment: Seriously...there are 20 other people who asked the same question. Searching for php mysql pagination on google will give you like 400000 results

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov thanks! it works now. but.. i really have no idea how that worked.

Comment: @user1551672 [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov i really dont see the difference it made when i added your given code. it was just an if statement. i really dont get it.

Comment: @user1551672 so you dont really see a difference between ` ` (empty line) and `$pagenum = isset($_GET['pagenum']) ? (int)$_GET['pagenum'] : 1`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov uhh well $pagenum already has a value which is 1. its already in the code. and i removed the (int) part so it's just $_Get['pagenum']. And the value is also one for that right?

Comment: @user1551672 and again [$_GET docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). Your `$pagenum` variable always will be 1

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!(isset($pagenum))) {
    $pagenum = 1;
}
```

you have not set $pagenum any where on this line instead it should be

```
if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) {
   $pagenum = 1;
 }else{
   $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
 }
```

it is just fix for your code, you need to improve the way you write code and try using PDO instead mysql functions